# Redmine - Large issues loading very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, apache, redmine

I am using Redmine helpdesk plugin for our support system and occasionally we do get tickets which tend to be very long. When one wants to open the ticket and view the content he/she has to wait good few minutes before the ticket is loaded.

Is there a way to increase the performance of Redmine?. I am running redmine on apache with very basic configuration:

```
PassengerPoolIdleTime 0
PassengerUserSwitching on

<Directory /var/www/redmine>
        RailsBaseURI /redmine
        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
        PassengerUser redmine
        PassengerGroup redmine

        AllowOverride all
        Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Redmine runs on Debian server

- ruby -v :

  ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
- rails -v:

  Rails 4.2.0

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the development environment by the production?

Comment: After not having used Redmine for some time? Or all the time ?